# Add another column to merged import range, showing which sheet the row came from

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to import ranges from two sheets, merge and sort them with the following, which is working with formula:

```
=sort(
 arrayformula({
  importrange("1qddSA1ec6SqoUorIVa4fVOtYoImiCVm-bZj0ug3czk8","CLIENT DATA!A2:B");
  importrange("1Q_eMaSefvcZFwgozBjAE8dGyEseJ4CUed1yxa98Gxzs","CLIENT DATA!A2:B")
 }),
1,
True
)
```

Now what I'd like to do is have a third column in my sheet which will show which sheet the data comes from. Eg. if the row comes from the first sheet it will show "Sheet1" and if the row comes from the second sheet it will show "Sheet2" in column C.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this could also be solved by autopopulating a column in each sheet with either 'Sheet1' or 'Sheet2', depending on which sheet it comes from. But how can I make this populate every row that is created?

Comment: Okay I've figured it out. I managed to auto-populate a column on the each source sheet which fills in the sheet number as follows: '=arrayformula(if(len(b2:b),"Sheet1","")'

Comment: You can answer and accept your own answer, and earn reputation for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below `ARRAYFORMULA` to `Column C`. It uses the `MATCH` operator to look if the value in each `Column B` cell exist in `Sheets` `1` & `2`. If yes, it prints `Sheet 1` or `Sheet 2` respectively, if no it remains empty...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="","", IFS(
    IFERROR(MATCH(B:B, {Sheet1!+Column}, 0),""),"Sheet 1",
    IFERROR(match(B:B, {Sheet2!+Column}, 0),""),"Sheet 2"
))
)
```